# Embedding Editable Google Sheets: Need Mobile-Friendly View

Tags: html, google-sheets, mobile, embed

Problem:
I need a Google Sheet on our members' daily workout signup page to be both editable and mobile-friendly.

Details:
We have a members-only page on our community rowing club Weebly site that includes an editable schedule. It's a Google Sheet open to all members to sign up for workouts. On desktop it's a properly formatted, editable doc but it's a mess on mobile. All of the tab names are superimposed on top of the table itself in large blue font. Looks like this:

[members page mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQsa3.jpg)

I've tried embedding the document using the Google Sheet embed code (File--Publish to the Web--Entire Document--Web Page) but this is a view-only, uneditable version. I've set the share settings to "Anyone on the internet with this link can edit" and it still isn't editable once it's embedded on our Weebly site.

The site was built by another volunteer a few years ago. This is the editable but mobile-messy embed code we're using now:

*iframe width=1400 height=900 src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILENAME/edit?usp=sharing"></iframe*

And here's the embed code provided by Google Sheet that gives us an uneditable but properly formatted table:

*iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/FILENAME/pubhtml?widget=true&headers=false"></iframe*

I've replaced "pubhtml?" with "edit?" but that doesn't work. I've added the widget=true&amp parameter to the new embed code; also unsuccessful. Can't find anybody else with the same problem and Weebly can't help me.

Thanks in advance if anybody can help out. I'm clearly not a developer, just a volunteer and fellow member of the club hoping to help.

Comment: To my knowledge, Google doesn't support this (and just has unresponsive embeds in general). The best option is to put in a link to the spreadsheet, because then mobile users will automatically have the sheet opened in the mobile-friendly Sheets app.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

If you can get your users to install the sheets app on their phone then you can link out to the normal sheets url and it should open on the mobile app.

Use Google Forms for data entry.

Sheets is exposed as an API. There may be a 3rd party tool (that stores the data to a sheet of your choosing) that would help out your specific workflow.